# Accidently uninstalled JDK

Tags: eclipse

I accidently uninstalled Java JDK. Now I reinstalled it again but there seems to be some problem with eclipse. Almost all codes are underlined red, like some kind of error but also with the codes that had no problem. Any kind help would be appreciated.

[The Screenshot of eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBs46.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your JAVA_HOME path is pointing to correct place or add this new installed JDK to project (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've added JAVA_HOME to point to your jdk directory into environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Preferences** from **Window** menu

Select **Java > Installed JREs** in *Preferences dialog*.

Your newly installed java JDK install should be listed in *Installed JREs*. 
If not in the list, add the directory using the **Add...** *button*.
Then make your new Java JDK the default one, bu clicking the check-box

In the Preference
[image]

Comment: You can also use the **Search…** button to have the system automatically look for all installed JREs and add them to the **Installed JREs…** list, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed ! But I avoid the full search as it is long, and it will add all the JVMs in my system, including those JVMs that are bundled inside software products I installed.